# Flexible authentication solution for java ee

Tags: java, security, authentication, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0

Imagine you would like to build your next (killer) web application with java ee. Like many other web-Apps a user should register with his email (or via `OAuth2`) and recieve an email to verify his email address. After this a user can login, logout, reset his password and delete the account. Nice to have: Backoffice - Tool to manage the users.

Other Frameworks like ruby on [rails](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification) or the [play framework](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate) have this functionality build in or have addons.

Is there any java ee jsr/addon/library/framework that could help? Do i really have to reinvent the wheel?

Things like JSR-375 or apache shiro  are not suitable: No Emails, No Password reset, No OAuth2..

Comment: What's wrong using Okta and integrating with them?

Comment: Computer security is a joke. Huge companies who have a tremendous amount at stake still seem to get hacked on a regular basis. Forget user authentication. The best way to mitigate hacking is multiple firewalls with IP filtering and an excellent lawyer

Comment: i do not want to rely on a 3rd party regarding user login. And it is to expensive. But something like okta as framework/library would be a perfect fit.

Comment: Have you seen [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)?

Comment: I havn't seen Keycloak. Keycloak comes pretty close to the solution. Thank you very much!